# Rewriting Sigma Notation (Index)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

We had our quiz in Pre-calculus earlier and we argued about the index in writing sigma notation from a given expression.

$$1-2+3-4+5-6+\cdots -10$$

We were instructed to write the expression in sigma notation. I had my answer with
$$
\sum_{n = 2}^{11}(-1)^n(n-1)
$$
I was told that my answer was incorrect. So I want to ask if is it necessary for the index to be equal to 1?

Comment: [No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Notation).

Comment: Usually one would choose for $\sum_{n=1}^{10}(-1)^{n-1}n$ but your answer is correct as well.

Comment: I can't imagine how anyone could say your sum is incorrect.  If it doesn't mean what you say, *what else could it possibly mean*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\cdots\\
\sum_{n = 0}^{9}(-1)^n(n+1)\\
\sum_{n = 1}^{10}(-1)^{n-1}n\\
-\sum_{n = 1}^{10}(-1)^nn\\
\sum_{n = 1}^{10}(-1)^{n+1}n\\
\sum_{n = 2}^{11}(-1)^n(n-1)\\
\cdots
$$

are all equivalently valid notations.

Comment: Thank you, sir.

Comment: Don't forget any variation like $\sum_{わ = 1}^{10} (-1)^{わ+1}わ$ and $\sum_{\dagger = 1}^{10}(-1)^{\dagger +1}\dagger$, but maybe stay away from $\sum_{5 = 1}^{10}(-1)^{5+1}5$.

Comment: Sir, might also ask, are there any conventions or rules to follow in rewriting expressions like these into sigma notation?

Comment: @AimanZylle: no, just common sense.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything wrong with your sum. It's a bit quirky and unusual to start at $n = 2$ in this case, but it's not wrong, and it's not necessary to start at $1$. (As a reality check: why would we *specify* that we start at $1$ the times that we do, if it's a necessity? This isn't an airtight argument, mind you. Notation can be superfluous at times.)

Comment: Thank you very much, sir.

Comment: Sir, might ask, are there any conventions or rules to follow in rewriting expressions like these into sigma notation?

Comment: @AimanZylle It should be correct, and preferably as readable as possible. Other than that, you're free to write them as you see fit.

Comment: Thank you, sir.